# How to position these images in CSS?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have some trouble positioning 2 images next to some reviews in CSS.

This is what my reviews are supposed to look like:

[image]

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

How can I position the first line of this text next to the images? I've tried to put the text in a paragraph, that will end up with the first line being below the author image. Now I've tried to put the text in a div, but that'll end up like in the 2nd picture.

This is the code I've used for my reviews:

```
<div id="recensies_order">
    <div class="reviews item1"><img style="margin-right:10px;" src="quotes.png" alt="quote" /><img src="author.png" alt="authorpic" /> <span>In één woord ge-wel-dig! Mooie designs en een super service. Logodealxxx heeft ons versteld doen staan van hun diensten. Wij raden iedereen dit bedrijf aan! </span></div>
    <div class="reviews item2"><img style="margin-right:10px;" src="quotes.png" alt="quote" /><img src="author.png" alt="authorpic" /> <span>In één woord ge-wel-dig! Mooie designs en een super service. Logodealxxx heeft ons versteld doen staan van hun diensten. Wij raden iedereen dit bedrijf aan! </span></</div>
    <div class="reviews item3"><img style="margin-right:10px;" src="quotes.png" alt="quote" /><img src="author.png" alt="authorpic" /> <span>In één woord ge-wel-dig! Mooie designs en een super service. Logodealxxx heeft ons versteld doen staan van hun diensten. Wij raden iedereen dit bedrijf aan! </span></div>
</div>

#recensies_order {
color: #ACACAB;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is *[floating](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)*.

In your scenario the following should work (untested):

```html
<div id="recensies_order">
    <div class="reviews item1">
       <img style="margin-right: 10px;" src="quotes.png" alt="quote" style="float: left" />
       <img src="author.png" alt="authorpic" style="float: left" />
       <span>In één woord ge-wel-dig! Mooie designs en een super service. Logodealxxx heeft ons versteld doen staan van hun diensten. Wij raden iedereen dit bedrijf aan! </span></div>
</div>
```

Of course those `style` additions, should be moved into your CSS file later.

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bYk4/)

Comment: Thx, this is much better! Now I only want to move the span tags a little bit down, so there's only one line next to the images? Span doesn't support margin-top e.d.

Answer (score 0):

add `float: left;` to all your images

Answer (score 0):

```
#recensies_order {
color: #ACACAB;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: italic;
width:400px;
}
#recensies_order img{
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    margin:10px;
}
#recensies_order img+img{
    width:64px;
}

.reviews{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

[image]

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LGAdX/1/)

change the with and you have this:

```
#recensies_order {
color: #ACACAB;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: italic;
width:300px;
}
#recensies_order img{
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    margin:10px;
}
#recensies_order img+img{
    width:64px;
}

.reviews{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

[image]

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/LGAdX/2/)

Comment: It would be cool if the text would flow underneat the images, except for the first line. Like in my examples

Answer (score 0):

There must be other code affecting the `spans`. You're code is fine. Images and spans are inline by default so it should do what you're after. You can do it with floats but they are *not* needed.

Here's a pen with your code, floated images and images set to `inline-block`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmJhL